# How to get the physical size of a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, files, size

I can use `ls -l` to get the logical size of a file, but is there a way to get the physical size of a file?

Comment: Please, define what you mean by "physical" size.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`ls -l` will give you the apparent size of the file, which is the number of bytes a program would read if it read the file from start to finish.  `du` would give you the size of the file "on disk".

By default, `du` gives you the size of the file in number of disk blocks, but you may use `-h` to get a human readable unit instead.  See also the manual for `du` on your system.

Note that with GNU coreutil's `du` (which is probably what you have on Linux),  using `-b` to get bytes implies the `--apparent-size` option.  This is not what you want to use to get number of bytes actually used on disk.  Instead, use `--block-size=1` or `-B 1`.

With GNU `ls`, you may also do `ls -s --block-size=1` on the file.  This will give the same number as `du -B 1` for the file.

---

Example:

```
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r--  1 myself wheel  536870912 Apr  8 11:44 file

$ ls -lh file
-rw-r--r--  1 myself wheel   512M Apr  8 11:44 file

$ du -h file
24K    file

$ du -B 1 file
24576   file

$ ls -s --block-size=1 file
24576 file
```

This means that this is a 512 MB file that takes about 24 KB on disk.  It is a *sparse* file (mostly zeros that are not actually written to disk but represented as logical "holes" in the file).  Sparse files are common when working with pre-allocated large files, e.g. disk images for virtual machines or swap files etc.  Creating a sparse file is quick, while filling it with zeros is slow (and unnecessary).

See also the manual for `fallocate` on your Linux system.

Comment: in which case this difference is important? can you make a practical example? thank you in advance.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader See updated answer.

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstand something, but it appears the first sentence is the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31437673/3701431 `du` would show  how much data can be actually read, while `ls` shows the extent to which disk sectors are allocated.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy (sorry to reply late) No, `du` shows the amount of disk actually in use by the file, while the apparent size (logical size) shown by `ls` is how many bytes a program would be able to read from it.  If the file is sparse, some of the read bytes would be zeroes, but they would still be delivered to the program that read them (just not from disk).

Comment: This was a really good answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda  I create a file with `fallocate -l 1M file`, `ls -h file` shows 1M, `du -h file` shows 1M too. Why doesn't `du -h file`  show zero ?

Comment: @LewisChan I believe this partly depends on what filesystem you're using.  You may want to ask a new question about this (and provide more information when doing so).

Answer (score 9):

I get the file size in bytes like this:

```
actualsize=$(du -b "${file}" | cut -f 1)
```